# Add a new row with data

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a new row to my Excel sheet using a macro but with data, I've search and all I could find is to add a new 'blank' row, and that's not what I need

I want when I execute the macro, create the row with some content in the cells, like:

`cell 1   | cell 2    | cell 3 | 
userId    username   user last name`

The information will be hardcoded formulas or simple hardcoded data that I want that every time the macro runs the rows will be created with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to insert data at row i. you can do this:

```
myWorkSheet.Rows(i).insert
myWorkSheet.Range("A" & i).value = userId
myWorkSheet.Range("B" & i).value = username
myWorkSheet.Range("C" & i).value = userLastName ' etc...
```

If you want to have the new row be a copy of the row above it (usually useful when wanting to repeat formulas), you can then do this:

```
myWorkSheet.Rows(i).insert
myWorkSheet.Rows(i-1).copy myWorkSheet.Rows(i)
```